# How to refer to subview's children in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, storyboard, iboutlet

Through storyboard, I have added a UIView (say Y) to another UIView (say X).

In Y, I have few controls A, B - labels, buttons and so on.

I have a viewcontroller class which controls everything for X.
Currently it has no references to Y, A or B.

My question is:

If I want to programmatically play with Y, A and B - without discarding my storyboard work - what should I do within my viewcontroller?

Can I directly put all outlets for Y, A and B into viewcontroller and do my stuff?
Or should I discard everything I did on storyboard, and add things programmatically right from X and then till A, B?

This question is not only from feasibility purpose, but also from design principles standpoint.
Is there any requirement I should adhere to - for referring A, B from viewcontroller such as x.y.a (and x.y.b) (small letters represents outlet variables to my objects above) instead of just y.a (and y.b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the references as IBOutlets to access the controls in code. Access the controls in the view controller with `self.y`, `self.a` and `self.b`. You could then change the view hierarchy in the storyboard without having side-effects on the code.